# Change Width,Height,X,Y of window In electron with Cubic Bezier And Animation Timing

Tags: css, node.js, electron, frontend, desktop-application

i want to move a frameless window to new position, by an animation and timing like Cubic-bezier , and like a css command,
How i can have a movement and a transition like CSS commands ?

```
transition:  cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
```